# Difference between "int f(int(fn)())" and "int f(int(*fn)())"?

Tags: c++, function, types, standards

```
int g()
{
    return 0;
}

int f1(int(fn)())
{
    return fn();
}

int f2(int(*fn)())
{
    return fn();
}

int main()
{
    f1(g);
    f2(g);
}
```

The code above can be sucessfully compiled.

I just wonder:

What's the difference between `int f(int(fn)())` and `int f(int(*fn)())`?

Why does both of them are legal in C++?

Answer (score 4):

`int f(int(fn)())` and `int f(int(*fn)())` are the same thing. A function takes a function pointer as parameter.

When we pass the name of a function as parameter, the function name is automatically converted to a pointer. So

```
int f(int(fn)()) {}
int f(int(*fn)()) {}  // redefinition error
```